# How do I make my file open in the same state it saved in?

Tags: mesh, armature, weight-painting

I have a man who has a armature and has been weight painted.  Whenever I open a saved file, he is in a weird meditation pose.  In order to clear it I have to go into pose mode of the armature and click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> repeatedly until he is back in his normal pose.  I then can continue working on him.  when I save it and open the new file he is again in this strange pose.  Not sure if this is related or not, but when editing him and I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo something sometimes his pose will go really crazy and I can't clear the rotation, position or scale and have to re-open my last save.  I would like to have this fixed so I can open my project and go strait to work and would like to know how to fix this.  I don't know if this helps or not but this just started happening 2 days ago, Thanks for the help!  [image]

Comment: You can try File-> Recover_Last_Session

Comment: That pulls up a really old session.  Also, I don't want to have to do that every time.  I'm wondering if I'm saving it wrong or have a setting set somewhere that I don't realize I have set.

Comment: You can try using the Pose library (at armature properties) adding the desired initial pose. Or you can try to add a keyframe for all the bones in the first frame. However, it's possible there is an issue with the rig, but it's hard to tell without being able to check the blend.

Comment: How do I post the .blend file?  If I post the .blend file do I have to worry about copyright or someone steeling it?